# Filter based on non match of string between columns in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr, filter

I have a large dataset with two columns (here I'll give an sample as example), which corresponds to complete species' name with authority, and other with only the species' name. I would like to create a new column with the non match between these two above, that is only the authority.

Data sample:

```
Column_A                              Column_B               
Crocidura jacksoni Thomas, 1904       Crocidura jacksoni     
Pelomys fallax (Peters, 1852)         Pelomys fallax         
Ictonyx striatus (Perry, 1810)        Ictonyx striatus       
Acomys cahirinus (É.Geoffroy, 1803)   Acomys cahirinus
```

I am currently done the following using dplyr and stringr, as I saw in other question here:

```
df$New_column <- df %>% filter(str_detected(Column_B, Column_A, negative=TRUE))
```

But I've been got this error:

> Error in UseMethod("filter") :
> no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "logical"

...or some of my columns aren't recognized.

This is the desired result:

```
Column_A                              Column_B               New_column
Crocidura jacksoni Thomas, 1904       Crocidura jacksoni     Thomas, 1904
Pelomys fallax (Peters, 1852)         Pelomys fallax         (Peters, 1852)
Ictonyx striatus (Perry, 1810)        Ictonyx striatus       (Perry, 1810)
Acomys cahirinus (É.Geoffroy, 1803)   Acomys cahirinus       (É.Geoffroy, 1803)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add the output of `dput(head(df))` to your post instead of the sample you shared? This will tell us what the types of data are, which may be causing your problem, assuming you get the error you shared from the sample data that you shared.

Comment: ```structure(list(user_supplied_name = c("Lavia frons", "Paraxerus ochraceus", 
"Lemniscomys griselda", "Nycteris thebaica capensis", "Hipposideros caffer"), matched_name = c("Lavia frons (É.Geoffroy Saint-Hilaire, 1810)", 
"Paraxerus ochraceus (Huet, 1880)", "Lemniscomys griselda (Thomas, 1904)", 
"Nycteris thebaica capensis A.Smith, 1829", "Hipposideros caffer (Sundevall, 1846)"), yr_discover = c("1810", "1880", 
"1904", "1829", "1846")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), not_known = list())```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the detect pattern using `str_remove` like this (Added some space to the pattern using `paste0` to remove this from output):

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(New_column = str_remove(Column_A, paste0(Column_B, " ")))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   Column_A                            Column_B           New_column        
#>   <chr>                               <chr>              <chr>             
#> 1 Crocidura jacksoni Thomas, 1904     Crocidura jacksoni Thomas, 1904      
#> 2 Pelomys fallax (Peters, 1852)       Pelomys fallax     (Peters, 1852)    
#> 3 Ictonyx striatus (Perry, 1810)      Ictonyx striatus   (Perry, 1810)     
#> 4 Acomys cahirinus (É.Geoffroy, 1803) Acomys cahirinus   (É.Geoffroy, 1803)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Data:

```
library(tibble)
df <- tribble(~Column_A ,                            ~Column_B   ,            
"Crocidura jacksoni Thomas, 1904"   ,    "Crocidura jacksoni"  ,   
"Pelomys fallax (Peters, 1852)" ,        "Pelomys fallax",         
"Ictonyx striatus (Perry, 1810)" ,      "Ictonyx striatus",       
"Acomys cahirinus (É.Geoffroy, 1803)",   "Acomys cahirinus")
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine changing the columns order!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution that not only gets rid of the superfluous whitespace but also removes the parentheses could be with `trimws`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(New_column = trimws(str_remove(Column_A, Column_B), 
                             whitespace = "[\\s()]")) 
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Column_A                            Column_B           New_column      
  <chr>                               <chr>              <chr>           
1 Crocidura jacksoni Thomas, 1904     Crocidura jacksoni Thomas, 1904    
2 Pelomys fallax (Peters, 1852)       Pelomys fallax     Peters, 1852    
3 Ictonyx striatus (Perry, 1810)      Ictonyx striatus   Perry, 1810     
4 Acomys cahirinus (É.Geoffroy, 1803) Acomys cahirinus   É.Geoffroy, 1803
```